# track down google apps script that sends e-mail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried looking at other questions and didn't find anything specific enough to help me in my situation.

I have main google sheets that I work off of and I am constantly writing new codes in the script tool to help my team and provide information to our customers. Something that I started doing (which is probably a bad practice in hindsight) is creating new google sheets and using SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl() to manipulate the sheets we work off of without writing thousands of line of code into the original sheets code file. I've been doing this for a while and due to lack of organization, I can't seem to find a google sheet I created that runs through one of my main sheets and sends an e-mail to one of our customers.

I send myself the e-mail as well, so I get the e-mail every day. No where in the e-mail is there anything that traces back to the file that the code is ran off of. I realized that the code never does anything on it's own file, so that file does not get pushed up to the top of my file list when I sort by last edited (in Drive).

Does anyone know of any way I can track down this file? Is there a way to get a list of all code projects I have in my account? Please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Last run` in My Triggers (Tools > Script Editor > Edit > Current project's triggers or All your triggers) should narrow you search.

Tools > File Open offers `My Projects` on the left.

Comment: Tools > Script Editor > Edit > All your triggers is exactly what I needed! I tried to vote this answer as the best answer but it wouldn't let me. Thank you mate! This page lists all of the functions that were run by a trigger. It shows the file name on the left hand side and the name of the trigger on the right hand side. Fortunately for me, I named the function appropriately so when I scanned through the functions I found it! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have the minimum reputation to put a comment)

It sounds like there are a lot of moving pieces going on here. Without narrowing down your search criteria it may be difficult to easily isolate the file in question. It may be possible to put some kind of unique stamp in the emails that can be correlated with the underlying file in question.

You may be able to go to https://script.google.com/home/my and on the right side of the page opening the settings for each project you can click on "Executions" to start digging into the scripts that are running.

Comment: This answer also worked! I went to https://script.google.com/home/my and the 'My Triggers' button brought me to the same page that pnuts lead me to. Thank you for your help!